# How can take value of length of pdu from label

Tags: c#, at-command

I'm sending SMS in PDU mode through flowing command. "length" is a label which shows pdu length.

My code is working when I write AT+CMGS=20 or whatever the length is but I want that code take value of label instead of writing static value in code, I'm using it below mention way but it is not working.

Can anyone help me about how can I write in code if I'm doing in wrong way?

```
string recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT", 500000, "No phone connected");
recievedData = ExecCommand(port, "AT+CMGF=0", 500000, "Failed to set message format.");

string command = "AT+CMGS=\""+ length +" \"";
recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 500000, "Failed to accept phoneNo");
command = p1 + char.ConvertFromUtf32(26) + "\r";
recievedData = ExecCommand(port, command, 5000, "Failed to send message");
```

Answer (score 1):

The line

```
string command = "AT+CMGS=\""+ length +" \"";
```

will produce `AT+CMGS="20 "`. If you want it to become `AT+CMGS=20` you should write

```
string command = "AT+CMGS="+ length;
```